# How to access values from angular $scope variable in MVC view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

The below function retrieves data from controller function and saves it to `$scope.Details` and redirect to payment view.

```
$scope.pay = function () {

          $http.get('api/Details/123').success(function (data) {
              $scope.Details = data;
          });

          $location.url('/payment');
      }
```

Also, I am initializing `paymentForm` scope to have the values from `$scope.Details` that are retrieved above.

```
$scope.paymentForm =  {
          FirstName: $scope.Details.FirstName,
          LastName: $scope.Details.LastName,
      PaymentAmount: $scope.Details.PaymentAmount
      };
```

Controller function:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Details/{id}")]
    public Details Details(int id)
    {
        return new Details()
        {
            FirstName = "Test",
            LastName = "Tester"
        };
    }
```

Payment View:

```
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
<input id="firstname" type="text" ng-model="paymentForm.FirstName">
<label for="lname">Last Name</label>
<input id="lastname" type="text" ng-model="paymentForm.LastName">
```

The payment form does not populate values in first name and last name fields. Can anyone please point out what I am missing here?
Thank you!

Comment: we're missing quite a bit here, like which angular controller you are assigning `$scope.paymentForm` in, and where the `ng-controller` directive is at in your HTML view.

Comment: Also, as an aside, your input elements are not (self) closed, angular may have some issues with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `$scope.Details = {}` just above the `$scope.pay` function declaration. Then this code should do the job.

Comment: Thank you. I will try these things.

Comment: I found that the payment view is saving values to scope variable paymentForm when I type into the controls on the form. But I can't populate default values on the view from the scope when the view is displayed first. Somehow, the data from $scope.Details is not going across to $scope.paymentForm. I tried $scope.$apply() after loading $scope.Details in the Pay() function and it did not work.Thank you!

Comment: Try creating an initial `$scope.paymentForm = {
          FirstName: '',
          LastName: '',
      PaymentAmount: ''                                                                                      }`                                                                                                                          Then on success alter the `$scope.paymentForm.FirstName = data.FirstName` and like that for the other props. You also shouldn't need the $scope.Details object this way.